# Nginx cakephp run subfolder

Tags: nginx, cakephp

I am using cakephp + winNMP (nginx+mariadb+php),
I have successfully run the web on nginx. http://localhost
I want to run a similar cakephp code in a subdirectory. eg: http://localhost/subfolder
My directory structure is :

[link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDWIA.jpg)
Is config nginx :

```
    root    "c:/winnmp/www/huyquangltd";
        autoindex on;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            #try_files $uri =404;
            include     nginx.fastcgi.conf;
            include     nginx.redis.conf;
            fastcgi_pass    php_farm;
            fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
```

http://localhost/ <-- ok
http://localhost/subfolder <-- not ok

Please help me or have any ideas!

Thank you